# Problems with Unit test on symfony

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, doctrine

)

Since 2 days I do unit tests on queries and I have some problems, here is the code and the tests:

request:

```
<?php

namespace CampaignBundle\Service;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use AccessBundle\Model\UserInterface;
use AccessBundle\Service\CountryFilter;

class CampaignProvider
{
    /** @var EntityManager */
    protected $em;

    /** @var CountryFilter */
    protected $countryFiler;

    /**
     * CampaignProvider constructor.
     * @param EntityManager $entityManager
     * @param CountryFilter $countryFilter
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager, CountryFilter $countryFilter)
    {
        $this->em = $entityManager;
        $this->countryFiler = $countryFilter;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository|CampaignBundle\Entity\CampaignRepository
     */
    protected function getRepository()
    {
        return $this->em->getRepository('CampaignBundle:Campaign');
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function getCampaign()
    {
        $queryBuilder = $this->getCampaignQb();

        return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
    }

    /**
     * @return \Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function getCampaignQb()
    {
        $repository = $this->getRepository();

        $queryBuilder = $repository->createQueryBuilder('c');

        $queryBuilder
            ->where('c.isDeleted = 0')
            ->addOrderBy('c.id', 'DESC');

        return $queryBuilder;
    }
}
```

Test:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: mickael
 * Date: 24/12/18
 * Time: 14:10
 */

namespace CampaignBundle\Tests\Service;

use Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use AccessBundle\Service\CountryFilter;
use CampaignBundle\Entity\Campaign;
use CampaignBundle\Service\CampaignProvider;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationCheckerInterface;

class CampaignProviderTest extends KernelTestCase
{
    /** @var EntityManager */
    private $entityManager;

    /** @var CampaignProvider */
    private $campaignProvider;

    /** @var CountryFilter */
    private $countryFilter;

    /** @var TokenStorageInterface */
    private $tokenStorage;

    /** @var AuthorizationCheckerInterface */
    private $authorizationChecker;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->entityManager = $this->getMockBuilder('\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();

        $this->tokenStorage = $this->getMockBuilder('Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();

        $this->authorizationChecker = $this->getMockBuilder('Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationCheckerInterface')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();

        $this->countryFilter = new CountryFilter($this->tokenStorage, $this->authorizationChecker, $this->entityManager);

        $this->campaignProvider = new CampaignProvider($this->entityManager, $this->countryFilter);
    }

    public function testGetCampaign()
    {
        $queryBuilder = $this->getMockBuilder('Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder')
            ->setMethods(array('getQuery', 'getCampaignQb'))
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();

        $queryBuilder->expects($this->once())
            ->method('getCampaignQb')
            ->will($this->returnValue($queryBuilder));

        $queryBuilder->expects($this->once())
            ->method('getQuery')
            ->will($this->returnValue($queryBuilder));

        $queryBuilder->expects($this->once())
            ->method('getResult')
            ->will($this->returnValue($queryBuilder));

        $this->campaignProvider->getCampaign();
    }

    public function testGetCampaignQb()
    {
        $repository = $this->getMockBuilder('\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->setMethods(array('createQueryBuilder'))
            ->getMock();

        $queryBuilder = $this->getMockBuilder('Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder')
            ->setMethods(array('where', 'addOrderBy', 'createQueryBuilder'))
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();

        $repository->expects($this->once())
            ->method('createQueryBuilder')
            ->will($this->returnValue($queryBuilder));

        $queryBuilder->expects($this->once())
            ->method('where')
            ->will($this->returnValue($queryBuilder));

        $queryBuilder->expects($this->once())
            ->method('addOrderBy')
            ->will($this->returnValue($queryBuilder));

        $entityManager = $this->getMockBuilder('\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();

        $entityManager->expects($this->once())
            ->method('getRepository')
            ->will($this->returnValue($repository));

        $this->campaignProvider->getCampaignQb();
    }
}
```

When I run the tests I get:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function createQueryBuilder() on null in
```

I admit that I have some problems when it comes to testing the queries, can you help me please?

Thank you ;)

**edit :
edit my all post**

ps: CountryFilter its a service i call in CampaignProvider

Comment: Have you declared the repository class in your entity one ?

Comment: hello, yes i did it ( i edited my post to show how i get the repository too )

Comment: Can you past the whole classes please ! not just the methods. Thanks !

Comment: i edited again sorry

Answer (score 1):

You're mocking the entity manager, but you're not passing it to the CampaignProvider in your tests: `$this->campaignProvider` doesn't know about the local `$entityManager` variable.

You need to either put it in the constructor call if you're using constructor injection or in a `setEntityManager` method if you're using method injection.

Comment: hello, normaly i did it in a setUp in the test class, i edited my post you can see it now

Comment: In your tests, you're still using local variables (`$repository` and `$entityManager`), but you should use the ones you created in the `setUp` function instead (`$this->repository` and `$this->entityManager`). You do not have to create new mocks for them.